# Conditions in RowSouce property of a ComboBox

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to display a `ComboBox` with the names of the Doctors of a table with two columns, `NAME` and `TYPE`. The `TYPE` can be `DOCTOR` or `AUX`.

I think I should start with:

```
ComboBox.RowSource = "TableName[TYPE]"
```

I would like to know how to tell them only to display the Doctors.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: There is no way to filter the `RowSource` directly. You need to apply a autofilter to your table. Copy the filtered result into a (hidden) temporary sheet and use that as `RowSource`. Alternatively you can loop throught the filtered table and fill the combobox item by item with VBA. • Give that a try and if you get stuck or errors come back with your attempt.

Comment: Thanks, I've solved it with a table in a hidden sheet and it's working perfectly.

Comment: @Rober I wrote it as an answer so you can mark this question as solved.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to filter the `RowSource` directly. You need to apply a autofilter to your table. Then copy the filtered result into a (hidden) temporary sheet and use that as `RowSource`.

Alternatively you can loop through the filtered table and fill the combobox item by item with VBA.